# error C2065: 'Test_Proc' : undeclared identifier which 'Test_Proc' already exists

Tags: c, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

**ENV** vc6.0

'Test_Proc' is already exists in 'TestDlg.h'. and `#include "TestDlg.h"` is in this file.

'Test_Proc' is used like this:

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd,GWL_HINSTANCE);
DialogBoxParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_PRESENTTYPE), hWnd, Test_Proc,NULL);
```

TestDlg.cpp

```
#include "TestDlg.h"

BOOL WINAPI Test_Proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_INITDIALOG, Test_OnInitDialog);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, Test_OnCommand);
        HANDLE_MSG(hWnd,WM_CLOSE, Test_OnClose);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

TestDlg.h

```
#ifndef _LOGIN_H
#define _LOGIN_H

#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI Test_Proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL Test_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
void Test_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify);
void Test_OnClose(HWND hwnd);

#endif
```

**error**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\MyProjects\mm1\SearchMemberDlg.cpp(378) : error C2065: 'Test_Proc' : undeclared identifier
```

The erros is wired. Anyone has similar experiences? Thank you.

Is there something wrong with vc6.0?

Comment: what is winapi in front of your function ?

Comment: Please **copy/paste** the error message from the compiler.

Comment: @user3018144 Just copy other codes which works for other dialog.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have added the error. see **error**

Comment: will #ifdef Test_Proc \n #warning "Properly defined" \n #endif raise a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SearchMemberDlg.cpp must `#include "TestDlg.h"` and you should change the include guard in TestDlg.h from `_LOGIN_H` to `TESTDLG_H_INCLUDED`, otherwise you might have problems if you include `TestDlg.h` after `Login.h`.